# how to un-append an appended variable

Tags: python, append

How would I unappend these appended variable:

```
if letterchoice == wordchoice[0]:
    wc = []
    for each in wordchoice:
        wc.append(each)
    wh = []
    for each in wordhidden:
        wh.append(each)
    wh[0] = wc[0]
```

This is for part of a hangman program(I understand that this is probably not the most efficient way of doing this but I am new to python and wanted to give myself a challenge)

Comment: What do you mean by "unappend" the variable? Do you mean to remove them?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, but you can use e.g. `.pop` to remove an element from a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can remove item from a list, you can delete by the value or by the index:

```
>>> foo = [1,2,3,4]
>>> foo.pop(1)
2
>>> foo
[1, 3, 4]
>>> foo.remove(1)
>>> foo
[3, 4]
>>> del foo[1]
>>> foo
[3]
>>>
```

Nevertheless, I suggest to use `.pop()`.

Edit: Based on your comment, is this what you want to do?

```
>>> foo = ['h', 'm', 'f', 'd', 's']
>>> foo
['h', 'm', 'f', 'd', 's']
>>> ''.join(foo)
'hmfds'
>>>
```

Comment: no i mean that my code there makes wc look like ['h', 'm', 'f', 'd', 's'] i want to know a function to return it to a single string

Comment: Do you mean return it as `'hmfds'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the python list `pop()` method, [which](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_pop.htm) `removes and returns last object or obj from the list` i.e.

```
wh.pop()
```

To avoid popping from an empty list, consider checking first:

```
if wh:        # Makes sure there is something to pop()
    wh.pop()
```

Also, you may want to "catch" the popped entry and avoid it from being printed to the terminal, as in:

```
if wh:
    x = wh.pop()
```